# How to authenticate user using mobile number in Keycloak

Tags: authentication, keycloak, openid, phone-number, keycloak-rest-api

User has a custom attribute phoneNumber in Keycloak.

There is a default method for fetching token using username and password but would it be possible to authenticate using phoneNumber / password instead of username / password

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" -d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "username=$UNAME" -d "password=$PASSWORD" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "$KEYCLOAKHOST/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

What call should I use to authenticate using a custom attribute in UserModel

Answer (score 1):

After looking around, it seems to me that you will not have the functionality provided by Keycloak out-of-the-box. With the current Keycloak implementation, it would not be feasible to use the:

```
curl \
  -d "client_id=$CLIENT_ID" 
  -d "client_secret=$CLIENT_SECRET" \
  -d "phoneNumber=$PhoneNumber" \
  -d "password=$PASSWORD" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "$KEYCLOAKHOST/auth/realms/$REALM/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

because neither Keycloak itself checks that the user attribute `phoneNumber` is a valid number nor does it check that it is a **unique number**. This last constraint is fundamental for obvious reasons, hence the reason why Keycloak enforces the usernames to be unique.

So you can try to extend `Keycloak` with that functionality, which was recently done in a production environment. Fortunately, the developer was nice enough to provide that functionality for others to implement; check out this [redhat blog post by the developer] [1](https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2020/10/23/use-mobile-numbers-for-user-authentication-in-keycloak/) detailing the implementation.

However, if you only want to use the "*default method for fetching* " that you posted in the question, then what you can do is just *say* that the username itself has to be the mobile phone (similar to the WhatsApp approach), which is not as bad as it sounds because 1) Keycloak enforces that the usernames are unique, and 2) Keycloak still has the fields first name and last name to identify by name the users.

Now the tricky part is to ensure that during the user registration, the user really inserts a valid phone number and not some random string. For that, you can either extend the keycloak and validate it there. However, if you are going this route, you might as well use the feature from the RedHat blog post. Or manage the user registration with your own app, which would enforce the user to add a valid phone number by relying on some SMS security feature, and after the validation was performed, the app itself would register the user on Keycloak with the username field set to the user phone number.